# How control screen orientation of Android device

Tags: android, rotation, screen, orientation

How I can control programmatically screen orientation of overall device and change it?
Here links to some apps that can do that:

http://dandroidtabletpc.com/download-total-screen-control-1-9-3-full-android-apk.html/

http://ru.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/ultimate-rotation-control_bznhn.html

maybe somebody knows open source projects like this?

Answer (score 13):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
}
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: This seems to only affect the current activity rather than the entire phone.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two approaches I know of:

#### Forcing screen orientation

If you want the orientation you set to override apps' own orientation preferences, follow the instructions in [How can I globally force screen orientation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14862852/238753).

#### Changing orientation non-forcefully

If you don't want the orientation you set to override apps' own orientation preferences, first ensure the phone's automatic rotation is turned off:

```
Settings.System.putInt(
    this.contentResolver,
    Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION,
    0 //0 means off, 1 means on
);
```

Then set the phone's user orientation:

```
Settings.System.putInt(
    getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.USER_ROTATION,
    Surface.ROTATION_0 //Use any of the Surface.ROTATION_ constants
);
```

Don't forget to check the return values of `putInt` to ensure the change was successful.

Also, I think you need the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in android if you are not setting any orientation either through code or xml file then your app by default has orientation.

And if your requirement is that inspite of phone is in portrait/landscape mode and you require an single oreintation then you can lock it through code as follow in oncreate method::

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  //or
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: This seems to only affect the current activity rather than the entire phone.

Answer (score -1):

Using below code you can get  current orientation of activity.

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
     Log.v(TAG,"Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");              
}
else if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");               
}
else if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE");
}
else if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED");
}
```

Then using below code you can set activity  orientation to either portrait or landscape.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: This seems to only affect the current activity rather than the entire device.