# using "USER_ROTATION" for API lower than 11 in Android (workaround?)

Tags: android, rotation

In my app I'm using the following command :

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, m_lockedInOrientation)
```

As mentioned in the [Android site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#USER_ROTATION) this will set the default orientation when android can't find one. :

> Default screen rotation when no other policy applies. When
>   ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION is zero and no on-screen Activity expresses a
>   preference, this rotation value will be used.

Currently this is the only reason why my app is not working on Android 2.X but only 3.X+ ..
Does anyone aware of a way to workaround it ?

Comment: Knowing why you need to set this system preference would be useful. I you only need to control your own application's default rotation, then there's a different way to do this. If you are really needing to set this preference system-wide then there's probably not a workaround as this setting simply doesn't exist on Android < honeycomb.

Comment: The app is a tool for controlling the system orientation , so it's not only for my app

Comment: If you want to override other apps' orientations rather than just specify the default system orientation, take a look at [How can I globally force screen orientation in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587085/how-can-i-globally-force-screen-orientation-in-android).

Comment: Use getRotation() method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()

Answer (score 0):

```
 //vetical position
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // Make to run your application only in portrait mode
  //HORIZONDEL setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation