# How to rotate a button appropriately?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, rotation

I am working on a project for the university using Android.

I have a layout -XML- with a simple button, I would like to rotate it so that it is always in the same position, independently if the phone is in portrait mode or in horizontal mode

I'm just trying to rotate a button, I do not want any animation.

Here is my sample XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:padding="5dp">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/punto3"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="177dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"


    android:rotation="90"


    android:text="3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**FIRSTLY:**
I added: android:rotation="90" to rotate from horizontal to vertical my rectangle -button-.

**Secondly:**
I check Design page, I got this:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPWyW.png

**Question**
How can I rotate my button without animation or calculations? Just a simple turn.
Something easy. Because I checked this questions: [Android: Rotate whole layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355784/android-rotate-whole-layout[1]).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does rotation in xml works for you? Cus if it works you can try punto3.setRotation(angle).

Comment: It works, but when I want to move my button to the left margin - in contact with the edge of the left screen - I can not. the button thinks it is still in horizontal mode.

Comment: Replace RelativeLayout with ConstraintLayout if setRotation works. set `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf=parent` in portrait mode

Comment: rotation is little tricky when you come to View's as per ur need u have to set the pivotX and pivotY around which u want to rotate and then rotate the view.In your Screenshot view's Pivot are at centre of the view change pivotX and pivotY to (0,0)

@JaimeGar

Comment: Thank you all. I will try to force open in Landscape. Everything you all said work, but if i rotate all my LinearLayout (android:layout_weight="1") does not work correctly.