# Is it possible to Change the horizontal and vertical position of the display in android like we do it for TVs and monitors

Tags: android

Is it possible to Change the horizontal and vertical position of the display in android like we do it for TVs and monitors.If possible please suggest me the way,even through Adb shell commands.I have been trying since last 1 week and couldn't sort out.Any help is Appreciated

Comment: In short, you can't. The displays function entirely differently.

Answer (score -1):

If looking to change it for your application you can change it for the whole app or just the activity :

```
 <application android:name=".Application"
       android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

If looking to control all apps and forcing an orientation, you need to create a System Attached window and control that window. This uses the System Alert Window, much like the Facebook Messenger Application.

[**HERE IS A FULL EXAMPLE WITH EXPLANATION, possible duplicate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587085/how-can-i-globally-force-screen-orientation-in-android/14862852#14862852)

Comment: If it's a duplicate question, mark it as such. Simply copying another answer adds noise and is unhelpful. That aside, you didn't understand the question, and plagiarized an answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I have posted links in other comments to be reprimanded for not copying in the pertinent bits of the original post, even citing it as a potential duplicate. Maybe some clarifications would be good on policy? Original post is linked for SO.

Comment: Actually that is not what I have asked.Kindly check the question clearly again.I am asking for changing the complete system.i.e.,Display positioning like in Tvs. @childofthehorn.