# How some apps change the orientation of other apps?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I've noticed that there are apps that let you control the orientation of the device, even though they are not the foreground apps, such as these:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation&hl=en

I know it's possible to change orientation of the current app, and I know you can handle orientation using adb commands, but how do you do it for any app, using the official API ?

Comment: @samgak Thank you. Will check it out.

Comment: @samgak this worked : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14862852/878126